# Adding multiple documents in array from each product in cart with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a bit novice in this so please bear with me. I want to present ability to customer to add multiple digital products (e-books, documents, pdf etc) in cart.

This is my function to add item(s) in cart

```
public function add($productId)
{
    /** @var Product $product */
    $product = Product::where('product_id', $productId)->first();
    if (!$product) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    $cart = Session::get(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());
    if (isset($cart[$productId])) {
        $cart[$productId]['quantity']++;
    } else {
        $cart[$productId] = array(
            'title' => $product->title,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'doc' => $product->file_id
        );
    }

    Session::put(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, $cart);
}
```

The field for documents is `'doc' => $product->file_id`. This is the blade view where I show all products added to the shopping cart before submit the order.

```
@foreach($cart as $productId => $item)
   <tr>
      <td>{{ $productId }}</td>
      <td>
         <div class="media">
             <div class="media-body">
                 <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $item['title'] }}</h4>
             </div>
         </div>
      </td>
         <td class="text-right"><strong>{{ $item['quantity'] }}</td>
         <td>
             <strong>${{ $item['price'] }}</strong>
         </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

When I have two products in cart and I do

```
{{ dump($item['doc']) }}
```

I see the ID only of first document added to cart. The second one is missing. How can I make it to add all of them in order, no matter how much are they?

UPDATE:

```
const CART_SESSION_KEY = 'cart';

public function index()
{
    $cart = Session::get(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());
    return View::make('cart.index', ['cart' => $cart]);
}

public function indexSubmit()
{
    $cart = Session::get(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, array());
    $input = Input::except(['_token']);
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $parts = explode('_', $key);
        if (
            count($parts) !== 2 ||
            !is_numeric($value) ||
            intval($value) < 0 ||
            !is_numeric($parts[0]) ||
            !in_array($parts[1], ['quantity'])
        ) {
            continue;
        }

        list($productId, $mode) = $parts;
        $value = intval($value);
        if ($value == 0) {
            unset($cart[$productId]);
        } else {
            $cart[$productId]['quantity'] = $value;
        }
    }
    Session::put(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, $cart);
    return Redirect::to('/cart')->with('message_success', 'Cart updated.');
}
```

Comment: do you send ajax request to add controller method ?

Comment: No, works without ajax, js etc

Comment: I am not sure how you handle adding cart but if you dont use ajax you can send 1 request each time

Comment: Yes, that's how it's work. I can add one item to the cart per click. The question is how to get the ID's

Comment: @AnarBayramov, I've added the index and indexSubmit function as well. They are responsible to add products too

Comment: are you sure you get first data? maybe you overwrite current session variable and retrieve second one ? I am not sure how `put` works 

but you can try something like get `$current = session::get(self::CART_SESSION_KEY); `
`$array = [$current, $cart] ;
Session::put(self::CART_SESSION_KEY, $array)`

Comment: Actually is not the first. It's the last product added. I got the the id from last product added here `{{ dump($item['doc']) }}`

Comment: so yes you are overwriting your session variable. I am giving you an answer right away